# How would I store a User's images to Google Firebase so that they can see a feed of only "their" images?

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, firebase-storage

What I am trying to do is store images to google Firebase's storage database through my app, and allow users to look at a feed that shows every picture they have submitted. Think of a typical social media user page, like Instagram.

The problem I am running into is that every picture I submit is stored in the general "gs://" bucket in Firebase, and if every user's submissions are intertwined. I do not see any kind of User ID's on the saved images in Firebase as well.

Here is my Swift 3 code for image submission:

```
    //Save to Firebase Storage
    let guid = "uid"
    let imagePath = "\(guid)/\.(Int(Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)).jpg"
    let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
    metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
    self.storageRef.child(imagePath)
        .put(imageData!, metadata: metadata) { [weak self] (metadata, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error uploading: \(error)")
                return
            }
```

What would I need to add to specify that it saves the photo under the certain User's ID? I understand that Firebase is not a SQL database but JSON, but I would be able to still store pictures sorted by User IDs, correct?

Thank you in advance, and apologies for any kind of code best-practice screw-ups. This is my first coding project ever.